# FirebaseErrorr: Missing or insufficient permissions happens, When trying to get snapShot

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I tried to get snapShot with React.js and Webpack, and had the error  Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. 
Thank you very much in advance.

I suspected my webpack setting is something wrong to make the async request. However, when I tried the simple async request with the same setup, there is no issue. On top of this, Getting document also works correctly. I'm totally lost what I should do next.

//App.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
      this.setState({ user });
      await createUserProfDoc(user);
    });
  }
```

//FireBase code

```
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const createUserProfDoc = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
  if (!userAuth) {
    return;
  }
  const userRef = firestore.doc('users/123');
  const snapShot = await userRef.get();
  console.log(snapShot);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error is come from the code you shared, it looks like the user doesn't have permission to read document `users/123`.

More likely you want to read the user's profile document, which is usually defined/keyed on their UID. In code that's be:

```
const userRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I made a very stupid mistake that I used firebase as production mode without rules.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside your auth function:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('test_data')
        .where('winner', '==', true)
        .get()
        .then((response) => {
          response.forEach((item) => {
            console.log(item.data())
          })
        })
    })
```